# Calculate NotMapped property when loading from EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

We do have an entity class defined as below:

```
[Table("Users", Schema = "Mstr")]
[Audited]
public class User
{
    public virtual string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public virtual string SurName { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual string DisplayName
    {
        get => SurName + " " + FamilyName;
        private set { }
    }
}
```

This is working just fine. Now we would like to extract the logic part `SurName + " " + FamilyName` to a helper class which is usually injected with dependency injection. Unfortunately DI is not working for an entity class.

Therefor my question: **is there any way to intercept the creation of new User objects?** Is there a method from EF which I could override to execute some additional logic after a User object was created by EF?

Comment: Do you want to extract the logic part, because many of the entity classes have the same 3 properties? if yes, the solution would probably be the use of an abstract base class.

Comment: No, we do have a plugin system in place which allows loading different logic via DI and it would be great if we could use this system also for EF entities.

Comment: Try to intercept `context.ChangeTracker.Tracked` event.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - thank you for your proposal. This is actually working fine! Unfortunately we do have some queries where we use **AsNoTracking()** for performance optimization and obviously the **tracked** event is not called in this situations.

Comment: In these cases I would create another class, that is independent from EF. Than another service has a method which gets as parameter the EF entity (or a list of it) and produces this newly defined class. This service can use normal DI to calculate some specific values or use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org) to convert between these simple things.

Comment: You should consider re-architecting your solution for better separation of concerns.  I maybe reading into this based on the property's name but having a read only property with the name DisplayName in your entity model seems like there is presentation logic/data within your persistence layer.  Which would also lead me to believe that this entity model is probably being used from the data all the way up to the presentation layer.  If you'd like I could write up an answer that discusses this further.  Then you can down vote me for making such assumptions :)

Comment: At a minimum you should remove the private setter.  The way this is written it is a read only property and there should be no setter at all.

Comment: @marcobirchler JIC updated to EF 7 approach which in my opinion is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually (at least in EF Core 6) you can use DI when constructing entities. Solution is a little bit hacky and based on the EF Core capability to [inject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#injecting-services) "native" services like the context itself into entities constructors:

> Currently, only services known by EF Core can be injected. Support for injecting application services is being considered for a future release.

And [`AccessorExtensions.GetService<TService>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.accessorextensions.getservice?view=efcore-6.0) extension method which seems to support resolving services from DI.

So basically just introduce ctor accepting your `DbContext` as a parameter to the entity and call `GetService` on it and use service:

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {        
    }

    public MyEntity(SomeContext context)
    {
        var valueProvider = context.GetService<IValueProvider>();
        NotMapped = valueProvider.GetValue();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string NotMapped { get; set; }
}


// Example value provider:
public interface IValueProvider
{
    string GetValue();
}

class ValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    public string GetValue() => "From DI";
}
```

Example context:

```cs
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext(DbContextOptions<SomeContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

And example:

```cs
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IValueProvider, ValueProvider>();
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(builder => 
    builder.UseSqlite($"Filename={nameof(SomeContext)}.db"));
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
// init db and add one item
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var someContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeContext>();
    someContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    someContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    someContext.Add(new MyEntity());
    someContext.SaveChanges();
}

// check that value provider is used
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var someContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeContext>();
    var myEntities = someContext.Entities.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(myEntities.First().NotMapped); // prints "From DI"
}
```

Note that `var valueProvider = context.GetRequiredService<IValueProvider>();` will throw if service is not registered so possibly next implementation is better:

```
public MyEntity(SomeContext context)
{
    var serviceProvider = context.GetService<IServiceProvider>();
    var valueProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<IValueProvider>();
    NotMapped = valueProvider?.GetValue() ?? "No Provider";
}
```

Also you can consider removing not mapped property and creating separate model with it and service which will perform the mapping.

Also in 7th version of EF Core a [new hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#lifecycle-hooks) for exactly this case should be added. See this [github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15911) issue.

**UPD. EF Core 7 approach.**

EF 7 adds [`IMaterializationInterceptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.imaterializationinterceptor?view=efcore-7.0) (and bunch of others - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#new-and-improved-interceptors-and-events)) which can be used exactly for this goal. So updated code can look like the following:

No need for ctor accepting context in entity:

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string NotMapped { get; set; }
}
```

Create an interceptor and overload one of it's methods (I went with `InitializedInstance`):

```cs
class NotMappedValueGeneratingInterceptor : IMaterializationInterceptor
{
    public static NotMappedValueGeneratingInterceptor Instance = new ();
    public object InitializedInstance(MaterializationInterceptionData materializationData, object entity)
    {
        if (entity is MyEntity my)
        {
            var valueProvider = materializationData.Context.GetService<IValueProvider>();
            my.NotMapped = valueProvider.GetValue();
        }
        
        return entity;
    }
}
```

And add interceptor to the context setup, with our DI approach `AddDbContext` changes to:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(builder => 
    builder.UseSqlite($"Filename={nameof(SomeContext)}.db")
       .AddInterceptors(NotMappedValueGeneratingInterceptor.Instance));
```

Comment: That is, if I understand correctly, I have to write a huge class in which I manually specify all the methods of all classes that must be NotМapped in order for this previously perfectly working attribute to start working. It sounds like a bullshit! Is there really no normal solution?

Comment: @EgoPingvina TBH not following. AFAIK attribute should work out of the box, this solution is for automatically filling data from outside of the database. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I have a getter-only property marked NotMapped. After updating the EF Core from version 5 to version 7, this field began to be called when calling SaveChanges (the same on version 6), which leads to NRE. I do not understand why.

Comment: @EgoPingvina do you have a [mre]?

Comment: No, but we can make a short zoom call, if you can.

Comment: @EgoPingvina please ping me in around 3 hours if it will still be relevant for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255761/discussion-between-egopingvina-and-guru-stron).

Answer (score 0):

In your DbContext or whatever your context file is called you can intercept the SaveChanges() method and override it with your own things. In my example I override SaveChanges() to automatically add my audit fields so I don't have to duplicate it all over the code in a million places.

here is  my example. So when a new object is being created you can override it. In My example I override both New records Added and Records modified.

These are notated at EntitState.Added and EntityStateModified.

Here is the code.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {

            var state = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(x => x.State).ToList();

            state.ForEach(x => {
                if (x == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    //Create new record changes
                    var created = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).Select(e => e.Entity).ToArray();

                    foreach (var entity in created)
                    {
                        if (entity is AuditFields)
                        {
                            var auditFields = entity as AuditFields;
                            auditFields.CreateDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            auditFields.ModifiedDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            auditFields.Active = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (x == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    //Modified record changes
                    var modified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(e => e.Entity).ToArray();

                    foreach (var entity in modified)
                    {
                        if (entity is AuditFields)
                        {
                            var auditFields = entity as AuditFields;
                            auditFields.ModifiedDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }

            });

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Since you said:

> is there any way to intercept the creation of new User objects?

You would want to do your logic in the EntityState.Added area of code above and this will allow you to intercept the creation of your new User and do whatever you want to do before it is saved to Database.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that the OP case about situations when data is fetched from DB, not saved.

Comment: I see in his post he directly ask "is there any way to intercept the creation of new User objects?". That to me definitely indicates on performing a task before a save happens, not a fetch on the DB, but perhaps his post has multiple questions, but my answer above will definitely let you intercept  the saving of something. Now if he wants to intercept the 'newing' up of a class then no it wont, but lets see what he says and I can refine answer if needed :)

Comment: Maybe you are right. But for me i does not make sense to do something like example in OP with not mapped property during saving data into the database.

Comment: You could be right, I'll await for the OP to let me us know !

Comment: Hi Guys, yes indeed I am looking for a solution which is triggered whenever I load the object from the database.